# Axon: Multi Command for single Aggregate

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I have a pretty nice idea for fine granular API command handling.

Our web API should provide single simple `update` endpoint, but you can provide multiple commands to it. Something like this:

```
POST /myAggregate/12345/update
[
  { command1Name: "command1Data" },
  { command2Name: "command2Data" },
  { command3Name: "command3Data" }
]
```

Within Axon this seems quite difficult to handle. Especially in combination with `@AggregateVersion`.

---

My first idea was to have a new `UpdateWrapperCommand`. which internally has a `List commands`. And then within the Aggregate, you use reflection to call the correct `@CommandHandler` methods:

```java
class UpdateWrapperCommand {
  List commands;
}

@Aggregate
class MyAggregate {
  // id, version, constructor, etc. pp.

  @CommandHandler
  public void handle(SomeCommand cmd) { ... }

  @CommandHandler
  public void handle(UpdateWrapperCommand cmd) {
    // iterate over cmd.commands
    // iterate over this.getClass().getMethods()
    // find correct method(s), and invoke it
  }
}
```

But when the `@CommandHandler`s also use `@MetaData` and/or Spring Bean injection, then it's getting really hard.

---

My second idea was to simple call `commandGateway.send` in a loop. But that blows up, because `@TargetAggragateVersion` must be set for every command, and you have to wait for every command to complete, before sending the next one. That's not nice.

---

Do you have any ideas for that?

It should load the aggregate once and then run all commands.

And maybe even have some transaction-like behavior: Apply all resulting events, or none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're best bet to get this resolved right now, without the need to wait to the [issue](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/991) you've added to Axon Framework's issue tracker, is to add an [External Command Handler](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/external-command-handler).

The External Command Handler is just a regular Component with an `@CommandHandler` annotated function on it. That method would handle your `UpdateWrapperCommand` and know the works to issue separate commands for every command payload contained it.

The loading optimization of the Aggregate as you're suggesting is however really tied to implementing a Batch Command solution. Although this is definitely doable in the framework, this feature isn't in place yet.
I'd suggest you keep tracking the [issue](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/991) you've created to follow the progress of it.

Hope this helps you out Benjamin!

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction means that is all or nothing, then probably the boundaries of each commands are not well modelled.

Without understanding of domain I would say options are:

1 Wrap all the commands in only one and apply to one handle-all aggregate.

2 Apply all the commands independently and in case of any failure then apply compensating actions.

3 Not to use commands at all and just apply the transactional logic over something simpler.

Comment: The commands are modeled well, that's not the problem. They are very fine granular, but it depends on the client if this granularity is needed or not. Of course I could use `ChangeName` and `ChangeAddress` for mobile clients and introduce `ChangeNameAndAddress` for desktop clients, but that doesn't feel DRY. Though I'd like to reuse the existing commands. `...` And additionally this is some kind of optimization for the server: It only has to load the aggregate once, and then run all commands. Instead of load aggregate, run command, apply event, persist, load aggregate, run command, ...